# Add only generic types that have different concrete types

Tags: generics, rust

Given `Base<Foo>` and `Base<Bar>`, is there a way to implement `Add` such that only `Base<Foo> + Base<Bar>` and `Base<Bar> + Base<Foo>` compile? ie. only add if the concrete types are different?

In my case they can be only 2 different types.

Example:

Given

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Base<T> {
    n: u32,
    _marker: std::marker::PhantomData<T>,
}

trait FooTrait {}
struct FooImpl;
impl FooTrait for FooImpl {}

trait BarTrait {}
struct BarImpl;
impl BarTrait for BarImpl {}
```

is there a way to implement `Add` such that

```rust
let foo: Base<Foo> = Base::new();
let foo2 = foo.clone();
let bar: Base<Bar> = Base::new();
let bar2: bar.clone();

let foobar = foo + bar;
let foobar = bar2 + foo2;
```

compiles but

```rust
let foo: Base<Foo> = Base::new();
let foo2 = foo.clone();
let bar: Base<Bar> = Base::new();
let bar2: bar.clone();

let foofoo = foo + foo2;
let barbar = bar + bar2;
```

does not?

I tried

```
impl<A, B> Add<Base<B>> for Base<A>
where
    A: DerivedATrait,
    B: DerivedBTrait,
{
    type Output = Base<A>;

    fn add(self, rhs: Base<B>) -> Base<A> {
        Base::new(self.n + rhs.n)
    }
}
```

but it only allows `Base<A> + Base<B>`, not the other way around, and an additional `Add` implementation swapping the bounds does not compile.

Comment: i'm not sure to understand what you want. you want [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=35bcfc516180fc182e2eb4eaab4edc44) ?

Comment: If you're using nightly, you might want to try looking into the [`auto_traits`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/auto-traits.html) and [`negative_impls`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/negative-impls.html) features. These should allow you to control what impls exist more precisely, but I'm not sure if they're applicable to your specific problem.

Comment: @VaillantEtienne, I want to `Base<Foo> + Base<Barr>` and `Base<Bar> + Base<Foo>` to compile, but `Base<Foo> + Base<Foo>` and `Base<Bar> + Base<Bar>` to not compile.

Comment: Do you need generics? Or can you just `impl Add<Base<Foo>> for Base<Bar>` and `impl Add<Base<Bar>> for Base<Foo>`?